# elasticsearch distinct query only returns 10 buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get all the the distinct values of a field in elasticsearch but I only get 10 buckets back.

I set my query like this:

```
GET /sdpjmx/kafkajmx/_search
{
"size": 0,
"aggs" : {
    "topics" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "kafka_topic" }
    }
}}
```

and even with the `size` set to 0, I still only get 10 back.

results in this:

```
{
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 948380,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "topics": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 3597,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 886819,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "__consumer_offsets",
          "doc_count": 10777
        },
        {
          "key": "EVENT_ONE",
          "doc_count": 4367
        },
        {
          "key": "ERROR_AUTH",
          "doc_count": 4365
        },
        {
          "key": "topic zds",
          "doc_count": 4364
        },
        {
          "key": "topicabs",
          "doc_count": 4360
        },
        {
          "key": "dynamictopic1",
          "doc_count": 3827
        },
        {
          "key": "connect-a",
          "doc_count": 3824
        },
        {
          "key": "topic12",
          "doc_count": 3820
        },
        {
          "key": "service_qa",
          "doc_count": 3820
        },
        {
          "key": "topic ad",
          "doc_count": 3819
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a size parameter inside the terms aggregation:

`GET /sdpjmx/kafkajmx/_search`
`{
      "size": 0,
      "aggs" : {
       "topics" : {
           "terms" : { 
               "field" : "kafka_topic",
               "size": 1000
            }
        }
    } 
}`

Answer (score 2):

```
GET /sdpjmx/kafkajmx/_search
{
"size": 0, //<-- This size is for query results and not agg results
"aggs" : {
    "topics" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "kafka_topic" },
        "size" : 0 //<-- it will return all aggregation terms
    }
}}
```

Comment: after es 2, it the aggregation terms size should be some large number.